# How to post an audio file from an API call using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to send an audio voice sms using an API call, but end up getting the error message {"message":"The voice file must be a file.","status":"error"}

```
$curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example/api/send',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['api-key: keyxxx='],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
        'recipients' => [
            '233550000000'
        ],
        'voice_file' => new CURLFILE('voice_message.mp3'),
    ]),
]);


$response = curl_exec($curl);


curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: That message comes from provider you use. So, you need their document.

Comment: I have gone through it, and I am doing everything right per the document. Is there something  wrong with the code that it doesn't read the audio file. Because using other language like node js, I get the voice sms to be sent, I am just having trouble with the php.